# Doctrine Listener preLoad - fired only one result

Tags: symfony, doctrine, listener

I have an entity post and an entity guest.
Some guest have access to certain post but not at all.

My entity Post contains Guest property in ManyToMany and a méthod isContainGuests that check if a Guest can have access to the post.

```php
class Post
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity: Guest::class, inversedBy: 'posts')]
    private $guests;

    public function isContainsGuest(Guest $guest)
    {
        if ($this->guests->contains($guest)) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I create a listener who check on preload if a guest can access to the post

```php
public function postLoad(Post $post, LifecycleEventArgs $event): void 
{
        if($this->token === null){
            return;
        }

        $user= $this->token->getUser();

        $guest = $this->em->getRepository(Guest::class)->findByUsername($user->getUsername());
                if(!$post->isContainsGuest($guest[0])){
                    throw new AccessDeniedHttpException($this->error_msg);
                }
```

That works ! BUT it works too.
When i call "all posts" method, if 1 post is not allowed, all post are in exception.

Answer (score 0):

I found an other way.

In my listener, if my route is not "all posts" methods, i execute my listener, but if is my 'all posts' methods, i execute my controller and my function isContainsGuest.

```php
if('app_getallposts' !== $this->request->getMainRequest()->get('_route')){
 if(!$post->isContainsGuest($guest[0])){
         throw new AccessDeniedHttpException($this->error_msg);
    }
}
```

```php
foreach($posts as $key => $val){
     if(!$val->isContainsGuest($guest)){
        unset($posts[$key]);
     }
}
```